# Having this problem while running my flutter app on the in-built terminal of VCS what should I do?

Tags: android, flutter

[image: The Terminal Message]
I already used to code on android studio using java programming now I am shifting to dart and the first error I face is this one how should I resolve it?

I just tried running the app and somehow it's crashing

Comment: If you use to code on Android Studio, why did you switch to this Jack of All trade VSC? AS is any day better and has inbuilt support for Flutter which helps in you in debugging and many other things. Also, this error seems to be caused by old gradle version, but I'd say instead create a new Flutter project in Android studio, select File -> New -> Flutter project instead of CLI.

Answer (score 0):

Check Your Internet Connection Frist..
and Run Terminal Code --
flutter pub upgrade

1- Try flutter clean before flutter upgrade.

2- Try flutter upgrade --force

3- If this didn't work, delete flutter and install it again. I struggled for a while with a similar error.